# SQL Server connection using local application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a simple question I believe. Because I was given a task to analyse data insertion into a SQL Server database and I'm doing it on the server (both DB and client application are installed on the same machine) if there is any chance that this client application connect to the server through the network?

This question has been raised after I repeatedly saved data from the application and at some point the normal 30-45ms time of calling the stored procedure went up to 90 seconds (same data set). I'm just wondering what may be the cause of this situation. I pointed out the network, because the server itself has had performance checks and it works properly.

Comment: what is your connection string look like?

Comment: Data Source=SERWER2012\XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User Id=XXX;Password=XXX;

Comment: Such issues are generally not related to the network at all, but to how the database is set up and being queried. 90 seconds for the same query might indicate a lock somewhere, but you can't do anything with that statement without proper analyzing. We can't answer this, and "the server performs properly" still means you can write a query that performs poorly.

Comment: Well, I believe it may be caused by a lock, I'll have to research what queries can cause a table lock within the application, because the query is just one line query with UPDATE, nothing more.